# Linux Server and Steam Integration Problem

Tags: server, steam

I have a Linux Server build on Microsoft PlayFab. My matchmaking algoritm is working well in test project. But I tried with my actual game which uses Steam API, I couldn't join the server. I looked on Unreal's forum and see exact my issue. He/she fixed with adding Steam dll's. But I don't know how to add .dll's into Linux build. Can someone help me? Logs says

```
SteamAPI_Init(): Sys_LoadModule failed to load: /home/ue/.steam/sdk64/steamclient.so
```

So I need to include steamclient.so file, and I did it but it doesn't recognize the file I added. I need to link (probably) those files but I don't know anything about Linux. I've tried copy my steamclient.so file to /home/ue/.steam/sdk64 but it says No such file or directory. After that, I tried to mkdir but it says same thing. Can someone help me please?

Comment: I've put .so file to wrong destination, it should be inside LinuxServer/GameName/Binaries/Linux. Now my server initializes SteamAPI but I can't connect again. This time it gives me this error;
src/common/opensslconnection.cpp (1616) : unable to load trusted SSL root certificates
I'm trying to upload SSL now. :/